# Interpolation over 2d unstructured grid data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have some [data](https://vdegner.de/owncloud/index.php/s/kggfsoPZ4gFWUPN) (x,y,z) lying on an unstructured grid and I would like to interpolate the data for visualization purposes.

I have already tried `scipy.interpolate.griddata`, the interpolation assumes everywhere the same value. After that I tried `scipy.interpolate.Rbf`, but this gets me a memory error (see code below).

Is there another method or other options which improve the result?

**Result-->**

[image: result]

**My code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata, Rbf

x, y, z = np.loadtxt('stackoverflow_example-data')
# griddata
points = np.reshape(np.array([x, y]),(z.size, 2))
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():1000j,y.min():y.max():1000j]
counts_I_grid_1 = griddata(points, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
counts_I_grid_2 = griddata(points, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear', fill_value=0)
counts_I_grid_3 = griddata(points, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic', fill_value=0) 

# Rbf -- fails due to memory error
#rbf = Rbf(x,y,z)
#counts_I_Rbf = rbf(grid_x,grid_y)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/path/code.py", line 14, in 
>           rbf = Rbf(x,y,z)
>         File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 198, in **init**
>           r = self._call_norm(self.xi, self.xi)
>         File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 222, in _call_norm
>           return self.norm(x1, x2)
>         File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 114, in _euclidean_norm
>           return sqrt(((x1 - x2)**2).sum(axis=0))
>       MemoryError

```
# plot the result
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.title('Data')
plt.gca().set_aspect((x.max() - x.min()) / (y.max() - y.min()))
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=2, edgecolor='', marker=',')
plt.colorbar(ax=ax1)
plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.ylim(y.min(), y.max())
plt.xticks([20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3])
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.title('nearest')
plt.imshow(counts_I_grid_1.T, origin='lower',
           extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()),
           aspect=(x.max() - x.min()) / (y.max() - y.min()),
           vmin=0,vmax=36)
plt.colorbar(ax=ax2)
plt.xticks([20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3])
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.title('linear')
plt.imshow(counts_I_grid_2.T, origin='lower',
           extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()),
           aspect=(x.max() - x.min()) / (y.max() - y.min()),
           vmin=0,vmax=36)
plt.colorbar(ax=ax2)
plt.xticks([20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3])
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.title('cubic')
plt.imshow(counts_I_grid_3.T, origin='lower',
           extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()),
           aspect=(x.max() - x.min()) / (y.max() - y.min()),
           vmin=0,vmax=36)
plt.colorbar(ax=ax2)
plt.xticks([20.7,20.9,21.1,21.3])
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: 1000 times 1000 meshgrid? that's 1 Million points. A bit much, don't you think? Try 200 time 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to a subtle mistake that is dangerous enough that I believe it's worth giving a full answer.

Consider this line:

```
points = np.reshape(np.array([x, y]),(z.size, 2))
```

Since your input arrays are 1d, you're trying to transform `[x,y]` into shape "(something, 2)". Note that it's valid to say

```
points = np.reshape(np.array([x, y]),(-1, 2))
```

to let numpy infer the missing dimension for you, and this would still not be what you want. When you construct the 2d array

```
np.array([x, y])
```

you're defining a matrix *row by row*, thereby creating an array of shape "(2, something)". When you call `reshape` on it, it will read the elements row-by-row by default, since numpy stores arrays in row-major order (like C/C++, and unlike fortran and MATLAB). This means that the resulting two-column array will first contain all the `x` values, then all the `y` values, rather than containing pairs of `(x,y)` in each row.

What you're actually trying to do is to *swap* the dimensions of your array, without touching its structure. This means that you have to transpose your matrix. This means that you have to use

```
points = np.array([x, y]).T
# or np.transpose([x,y])
```

instead. Note that while this has the same `shape` as your original, it has the elements in the proper order:

```
In [320]: np.reshape(np.array([x,y]),(-1,2))
Out[320]: 
array([[  20.7     ,   20.702   ],
       [  20.704   ,   20.706   ],
       [  20.708   ,   20.71    ],
       ..., 
       [ 852.356964,  852.356964],
       [ 852.356964,  852.356964],
       [ 852.356964,  852.356964]])

In [321]: np.array([x,y]).T
Out[321]: 
array([[  20.7     ,  852.357235],
       [  20.702   ,  852.357235],
       [  20.704   ,  852.357235],
       ..., 
       [  21.296   ,  852.356964],
       [  21.298   ,  852.356964],
       [  21.3     ,  852.356964]])
```

This will fix the inconsistency between your sample `x/y` points and `z`, and will produce the expected results. In my experience, `reshape`-ing is almost never called for. Often you need to flatten out an `ndarray` into a `1d` one, but then the `ravel()` method of the given array is best.

Results as proof: left, your original with cubic interpolation; right, the version with `points` fixed:

[image: before] [image: after]

Note that as [@MaxNoe suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968172/interpolation-over-2d-unstructured-grid-data/35977942#comment59597392_35968172), I reduced your interpolating mesh size to 200x200. And as they hinted, your memory error with `Rbf` most probably stemmed from this huge number of interpolating points.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation. It helped me a lot with understanding what went wrong.